# Dynamic Crystal sub report

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I am using C#, MySQL and Crystal Reports.

I am new to Crystal Reports and trying to generate monthly statement of customer. I have created a stored procedure which will return invoice number and amount, which is fine, showing many invoice number and amount.

But I need to show details of invoice by calling another stored procedure. Like if invoice number 1 contains 10 product then need to show product name in next line underneath. I don't know if this is doable using Crystal Reports or not. I have searched on internet about this. But not much information.

Comment: can you merge two stored procedures in to one procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Using sub report in crystal report,
In main report you have the detailed just for the main, but how about the sub report that depend on the result of the main?

i did some complixed report before and used sub report too but i did it will through reading some research and tutorials. All i know is you have to depend on your formula at crystal report Both main report and subreport has a formula parameter.