# MySQL Fix Length Column Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get Fix length Data from MySQL columns so i have created below query

`select (concat(products.name,'        ','x',products.UNITS,'             ',LPAD(concat('$',products.TOTAL),10,' ')) from table`;

Like :-

```
Pepsi               X2             $200
Coke1234234sdf      X3             $300
```

i am not sure which function can help me here.

Comment: Looks like job for presentation layer, not DB

Comment: i can not do this in presentation because i am directly pushing this data to reporting tool, as raw data

Comment: What's the reporting tool?

Comment: Crystal Report.. i need to created dynamic subreport but there is some limitation, so this is my workaround.

Comment: lpad, rpad, so what is the issue. But why crystal cant do this ... I would shocked to find that the db has to do it. Study up on crystal more.

Comment: i have asked same question regarding crystal report at this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359319/dynamic-crystal-sub-report